# Alternatives to the Public Suffix List for autofilling domain names?

Tags: javascript, url, subdomain

My web application takes in a URL and needs to find its domain. Is there really no way other than importing the Public Suffix List? I'm interested in other solutions because keeping the PSL up-to-date seems like a huge maintenance burden.

Comment: Might `SOA` records be a viable alternative?